# Line break on Text Area (Long) in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, long-text-area, line-break

i have one long text area field and i used it on my visualforce.
my long text area field value is

```
- Fees are valid only for the payment of the Grade specified in this Letter of Offer.\n- Fees include: 2 sets of school uniforms, fieldtrip around the xxx area, E-Book material, and in-house co-curricular activities.\n- Request for changes to instalment plans must be made 10 days prior to the due date of the payment.\n- Terms and Conditions from the Admissions Policy will apply.
```

, the idea is i change all '\n' to `<br/>` so it can put line break in one field. here's my visualforce look like

```
<apex:outputText value="{!SUBSTITUTE(JSENCODE(loo.Note_SA__c),'\n','<br/>')}" style="white-space:pre;" escape="false"/>
```

the outcome is not like my expected

- Fees are valid only for the payment of the Grade specified in this Letter of Offer.\
- Fees include: 2 sets of school uniforms, fieldtrip around the JABODETABEK area, E-Book material, and in-house co-curricular activities.\
- Request for changes to instalment plans must be made 10 days prior to the due date of the payment.\
- Terms and Conditions from the Admissions Policy will apply.

**in every end of the list there is '\' symbol.** i don't know where it comes.
Do you have any idea about this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<apex:outputText value="{!SUBSTITUTE(JSENCODE(loo.Note_SA__c),'\n','<br/>')}" style="white-space:pre;" escape="false"/>`

change this into this

`<apex:outputText value="{!SUBSTITUTE(JSENCODE(loo.Note_SA__c),'\\\n','<br/>')}" style="white-space:pre;" escape="false"/>`

It will works for you.
Thanks for the update @VigneshwaranG

Comment: it didn't work bro. i already use it but no use. have any idea?

Comment: Use \\\n since you need to escape the escape character added for escaping \

Answer (score 4):

a more simple and best solution would be to add the css pre-wrap which conserves New lines, Spaces and tabs,    Text wrapping

```
  <apex:outputtext style="white-space:pre-wrap;" value="{!donationText}" escape="false" /><br />
```

Please note donationText is a long text area

Answer (score 1):

Like @VigneshwaranG said. just create escape character for escaping .

so i replace `\n` to `\\\n`